# how to search for number digits and print the total in a text file for java?

Tags: java

I have a code that I need to find the most frequent digit number and print out the total number of the digits from the decimal numbers in my file. my code is:

```
65-43+21= 43
65.0-43.0+21.0= 43.0
65 -43 +21 = 43 
65.0 -43.0 +21.0 = 43.0 
65 - 43 + 21 = 43 
65.00 - 43.0 + 21.000 = +0043.0000 
65 - 43 + 21 = 43
```

the output should say:

```
Digit: 
18 0
```

How would I go by doing this? should I use a Character.IsDigit() function, or make an array for it? Can somebody help me out with this? Thanks.

Comment: I think your idea is fine (O(N)), very easy to implement and only requires a minimal amount of memory. Can't think of a way to beat this..

Answer (score 0):

Read text file char by char. Use Guava HashMutilset to store digit chars. Iterate over HashMutilset.Entrys and determine the char with max occurences.